# Как скомбинировать вектора в С++

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

есть вектора:

```
std::vector<int> one = {1, 2, 4};
  std::vector<int> two = {1, 2, 3, 5};
  std::vector<int> three = {2, 3, 6};
  std::vector<int> four = {4, 4, 5, 7};
  std::vector<int> five = {2, 4, 5, 6, 8};
  std::vector<int> six = {3, 5, 6, 9};
  std::vector<int> seven = {4, 7, 8};
  std::vector<int> eight = {0, 5, 7, 8, 9};
  std::vector<int> nine = {6, 8, 9};
  std::vector<int> zero = {0, 8};
```

так же к этим векторам есть ключ

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> rule = {
      {0, zero},
      {1, one},
      {2, two},
      {3, three},
      {4, four},
      {5, five},
      {6, six},
      {7, seven},
      {8, eight},
      {9, nine}
  };
```

даётся ввод: 15
и нам нужно скомбинировать вектора one и five,

чтобы на выходи получили: 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48

если ввод: 3

то на выходе мы получаем: 2, 3, 6

как реализовать комбинацию векторов ? Если ввод может быть любым целым числом ( 1, 56 или 46327)

Comment: У вас талант объяснять. Лично я нифига не понял =) Если ввод `15`, `3` ... Что это за числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обойтись без чисел. Рекурсия, работа с текстами:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string rule[] = {
    "08"   , "124" , "1235", "236"  , "4457",
    "24568", "3569", "478" , "05789", "689"
};

void combine(const std::string &prefix, const std::string &key) {
    if (key.empty()) {
        std::cout << prefix;
    } else {
        for (auto c : rule[key[0] - '0']) {
            combine(prefix + c, key.substr(1));
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string key;
    std::cin >> key;
    combine(" ", key);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion combine.cpp 
>
> $ echo 15 | ./a.out
>  12 14 15 16 18 22 24 25 26 28 42 44 45 46 48
>
> $ echo 3 | ./a.out
>  2 3 6
>
> $ echo 1 | ./a.out
>  1 2 4
>
> $ echo 56 | ./a.out
>  23 25 26 29 43 45 46 49 53 55 56 59 63 65 66 69 83 85 86 89
>
> $ echo 46327 | ./a.out
>  43214 43217 43218 43224 43227 ... 79637 79638 79654 79657 79658
> ```

Comment: Код полностью выполняет условия задачи
твой ответ дал подсказку для продвижения дальше 

но к сожалению для понимания твоего кода, мне учится и учится 
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Годится?

```
vector<int> make(int n)
{
    vector<int> r;
    if (n < 0 || n >= 100) return r;  // Ну на всякий пожарный...
    for(auto a: rule[n/10])
        for(auto b: rule[n%10])
            r.push_back(a*10+b);
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(auto x: make(15)) cout << x << "  ";
}
```

Для любой (разумной :), проверки в этот раз я не делаю, оставляю в качестве самостоятельной работы) длины

```
vector<int> make(int n)
{
    if (n < 10) return rule[n];

    vector<int> f = make(n/10);
    vector<int> res;
    for(auto x: f) for(auto y: rule[n%10]) res.push_back(x*10+y);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: для двухзначных чисел, этот код идеально подходит, остается только разобраться в нем для доработки под свою задачу

Comment: Ну вот на хрена так делать? Сформулировали задачу для двузначных чисел, получили ответ, быстренько изменили вопрос... Да делать нефиг, например, рекурсивно собрать... Работы на 10 минут. Только вот отвечать уже не хочется — опять, боюсь, вопрос будет изменен...

Comment: не подумай ничего плохого
при написании вопроса, увидел ошибку и скорректировал свой вопрос

ты очень быстро ответил на поставленный вопрос (не претензия, а восхищение)

Comment: Ладно, см. ответ...

Comment: спасибо, на основе твоих ответов я написал своё решения для задачи

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::vector<std::string> get_pins(std::string observed) {
  // правило
  std::vector<int> one = {1, 2, 4};
  std::vector<int> two = {1, 2, 3, 5};
  std::vector<int> three = {2, 3, 6};
  std::vector<int> four = {1, 4, 5, 7};
  std::vector<int> five = {2, 4, 5, 6, 8};
  std::vector<int> six = {3, 5, 6, 9};
  std::vector<int> seven = {4, 7, 8};
  std::vector<int> eight = {0, 5, 7, 8, 9};
  std::vector<int> nine = {6, 8, 9};
  std::vector<int> zero = {0, 8};
  std::map<int, std::vector<int>> rule = {
      {0, zero},
      {1, one},
      {2, two},
      {3, three},
      {4, four},
      {5, five},
      {6, six},
      {7, seven},
      {8, eight},
      {9, nine}
  };
  
  std::vector<unsigned int> nums; // это вектор observed. если observed = "123" то nums = {1, 2, 3}
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  std::string sums;
  std::vector<int> mixed;
  
  // преобразует  строку в число и помещает его в вектор
  for (char c : observed)
  {
        int digit = c - '0'; 
        nums.push_back(digit);
  }
  
  if (nums.size() == 1)
  {
        std::vector<int> options = rule[nums[0]];
        // по очереди i принимает значения options и записывает каждое значение в текстовый вектор result
        for (int i : options)
        {
            result.push_back(std::to_string(i));
        }
        return result;
  }

  if(nums.size() > 1)
  {
      // определяет функцию recursive_fun, которая рекурсивно находит все возможные комбинации пин-кодов.
      std::function<void(int)> recursive_fun = [&](int pos)
      {
          //прошлись ли мы по всем возможным комбинациям
          if(pos == nums.size())
          {
              result.push_back(sums);
              return;
          }   
          for(auto num : rule[nums[pos]])
          {   
              //добавляем текущее число
              sums.push_back(num + '0');
              recursive_fun(pos + 1);
              sums.pop_back();
          }
      };
      recursive_fun(0);
  }
  
  return result; 
}
```

где проверки являются

```
It(Tests)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> output = get_pins("8"); std::sort(output.begin(), output.end());
        std::vector<std::string> result = {"0", "5", "7", "8", "9"};
        Assert::That(output, Equals(result));
        
        output = get_pins("11"); std::sort(output.begin(), output.end());
        result = {"11", "12", "14", "21", "22", "24", "41", "42", "44"};
        Assert::That(output, Equals(result));
        
        output = get_pins("369"); std::sort(output.begin(), output.end());
        result = {"236", "238", "239", "256", "258", "259", "266", "268", "269", "296", "298", "299", "336", "338", "339", "356", "358", "359", "366", "368", "369", "396", "398", "399", "636", "638", "639", "656", "658", "659", "666", "668", "669", "696", "698", "699"};
        Assert::That(output, Equals(result));
    }
```

Comment: это точно ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin точно
проверки прошла.